# Spark dataframe - weblogic application error log analysis

Tags: apache-spark

I have a big data requirement to analyze the weblogic application exception error. My approach is as follows:

1. Stream the weblogic application error log into hadoop using flume or    other streaming tools.
2. Load the data into Spark Dataframe.
3. Write Spark SQL queries to analyze the error data

We have a DB error log table. I will use that as another data source to correlate the Web logic DB exceptions. The weblogic error data is CSV format, separated by two pipe symbols ("||"). But, the problem with the input data is, the last column data is spread over to multiple lines as shown below. Spark treats the continuation of last column on next line as "new line" and hence the load is getting failed. Appreciate if anyone has any thought on how to deal this issue.

||20160704||01:58:32,294||396c0a8e2470e7a21467611910768||com.seic.dataservices.impl.InstrumentSearchDoImpl||[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 0) ....INSTRUMENT_ID(1004915) PRICE_DATE(01-JUL-16) does not exist in Table TABEL_NAME. Price data not found.. ORA-06512: at "Qxx_xxx.ERROR_PKG", line 502 ORA-06512: at "Qxx_xxx.IM_PRICING", line 6221 ORA-06512: at line 1 )

-uk

Update: Edited the input dataset.

||20160704||00:32:48,544||c0a07f3289f452801467606768492||com.seic.dataservices.impl.GetInstDetailsForMaintImpl||[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'||ERROR||ExceptionFactoryMsg:  com.seic.dataservices.lib.DataServiceSqlException - Error - A SQL exception was encountered while processing this request. - EX4 -  - q02_Desktop_MS1#20160704003248544#4 - With Additional Info:  (Error Code:  6550 -  ) - Caused By (java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 25:
PLS-00302: component 'GET_ASSET_TEMPLATE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
)
com.seic.dataservices.lib.DataServiceSqlException - Error - A SQL exception was encountered while processing this request. - EX4 -  - q02_Desktop_MS1#20160704003248544#4 - With Additional Info:  (Error Code:  6550 -  ) - Caused By (java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 25:
PLS-00302: component 'GET_ASSET_TEMPLATE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
)
||20160704||00:32:48,551||c0a07f3289f452801467606768492||com.seic.common.presentation.exception.SeiExceptionHandler||[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'||ERROR||Non-SeiException
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error in DesktopAction base class (Exception)
    at com.seic.common.presentation.action.DesktopAction.execute(DesktopAction.java:368)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)

Answer (score 0):

Well I will give you a idea that what you can do.

Supose you always have a pair of rows never even ok. Try to do this:

```
rdd = sc.textFile('file.log').zipWithIndex()
rddFirsts = rdd.filter(lambda x: not(x[1] % 2)).map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
rddSeconds = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[1] % 2).map(lambda x: (x[1]-1, x[0]))
rdd = rddFirsts.join(rddSeconds)
```

With this commands it will work properly as you want. I know that, this could take long steps. But it works fine.

I tested in Spark 1.5.2

EDITED

---

For scala:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file.log").zipWithIndex()
val rddFirsts = rdd.filter(x => (x._2 % 2) == 0).map(x => (x._2, x._1))
val rddSeconds = rdd.filter(x => (x._2 % 2) != 0).map(x => (x._2-1, x._1))
val NewRdd = rddFirsts.join(rddSecons)
```

Comment: Thanks.. This works fine where the input dataset has only one record. But, when I have multiple rows, this is not working . I have edited my original post to add sample input dataset